# Display button from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have two activities/two XMLs.

I made a Facebook button inside `signactivty.java` (`sign.xml`)
and I want to display the Facebook button in `homeactivity.java` (`home.xml`).

How can I use a button that's created in another activity?

Please give me an example.

Comment: are the layouts of both sign.xml and home.xml the same?  I mean same number of buttons,images,or any other views?.Then there is a way

Comment: as i understand, you can define the button in a single layout(xml) file, then include it in your layouts with "<include " tag

Comment: @Farrokh could you give me example ?

Comment: also you can create a frame layout for show button in your activity and handle event for button with pass a value to fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create facebook_button.xml like this

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="@+id/fb_button"
android:layout_width="64dp"
android:layout_height="64dp" />
```

create sign.xml layout file and use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/facebook_button"></include>
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

and so, in your home activity too...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/facebook_button"></include>
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for explain :D .... 
btw if in the file facebook_xml has two buttons like (id="@+id/fb_button") and (id="@+id/google_button") and my question how to display just google button ? thank you

Comment: no problem, define more buttons and get them in your code, and make them visible or hide there using findViewById and setVisibility, tell me if you need more description

Answer (score 0):

first create a third xml

```
button.xml
```

and create a layout inside it with only the button view inside it
then include that xml file in whichever xml file you want
In your case include it in `sign.xml` and `home.xml`